# Как записать свойство и значение в переменную?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Для удобства чтения кода хотел запихнуть все в переменную, но так не работает:

```
const noticeForUser = document.querySelector('#noticeForUser');
const defaultNotice = noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';
```

Нужна помощь, как запихнуть в переменную свойство и его значение или какой есть альтернативный вариант решения?

Comment: что в итоге должно быть в `defaultNotice `?

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас может не работать. У меня все работает как надо. Какая-то ошибка на выходе? Каково итоговое значение `defaultNotice`?

Comment: Есть такой код:

const noticeForUser = document.querySelector('#noticeForUser');
const defaultNotice = noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';

Но в функции переменная defaultNotice не работает. В этом проблема

Comment: @Александр что вы подразумеваете под "не работает"? Равна `undefined`? Равна пустой строке? У меня ваш код прекрасно работает.

Comment: innerHTML не заменяет значение в DOM, когда я в функции использую свои переменные. Если в функции написать noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение'; то в этом случае в DOM происходит изменение.

Comment: @Александр *Если в функции написать noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';* - так вы же так и пишете, просто потом еще результат (саму строку) сохраняете в константу `defaultNotice`. Как что-то может не работать? Может просто ваши ожидания от поведения этих двух строк не совпадают с тем, что они реально делают?

Comment: Из переменной "defaultNotice " не работает, без переменной работает.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const noticeForUser = document.querySelector("#noticeForUser");
const defaultNotice = noticeForUser.innerHTML = "Введите значение";

console.log(defaultNotice);
```

```html
<div id="noticeForUser"></div>
```

Код прекрасно работает. Значение `innerHTML` переопределяется и сохраняется в константу `defaultNotice`.

Другое дело, что такая ваша оптимизация вообще не желательна. Почему? Потому что многочисленное присваивание - это вообще антипаттерн.

Например:

```
void function foo() {
    let a = b = 1;
    console.log(a); // 1
}();

console.log(b); // 1, но снаружи функции
```

Как видите, довольно легко можно допустить непреднамеренное загрязнение глобальной области видимости.

Конкретно в вашей ситуации такого не происходит, однако это все равно не отменяет того факта, что подобных конструкций лучше избегать.

Comment: а jquery это не антипаттерн?:)

Comment: @Александр ну это уже совсем другая история

Answer (score 0):

Что не работает, где не работает и почему не должно работать?

```js
let noticeForUser = {innerHTML: ''};
const defaultNotice = noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';

console.info(defaultNotice, noticeForUser.innerHTML);
```

Comment: когда я использую переменную в defaultNotice в функции, то в элемент не записывается новое значение, хотя переменная и у меня в консоле возвращает значение

Comment: const noticeForUser = document.querySelector('#noticeForUser');
const defaultNotice = noticeForUser.innerHTML = 'Введите значение';

Я не весь код описал сразу. Как в случае с кодом выше мне быть? Я хотел сократить код, чтобы удобнее было работать в функции.